# execute file from within nodejs, writing in it's stdin and piping stdout to a file

Tags: c, node.js, stream

I have this program (coded in C btw...), and i want to call it from inside my nodejs server.
I want to pass a string to it's stdin, while redirecting/piping it's stdout to a file.

I know that process_child has some methods to achieve this behavior, so i tried:

```
program = child_process.execFile('program');
fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
program.stdout.pipe(fileStream);    
program.stdin.end('hello world!');
```

This line `program.stdin.end("...")` throws some errors.

It should be like `echo "hellow world!" | ./program > file.txt`

```
//$ cat program.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char aux[100];

    scanf("%s", aux);
    printf("[%s]", aux);

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

Using `'./program'` instead of `'program'` solved part of the problem.

**Update 2**

Using `'hellow world!\r\n'`, or file.txt will just be empty.
But my program do not read \n, it reads using %s. 
As far as i know it will read until \n or EOF.
For example, `echo -n "mimimi" | ./test` works (no \n in stdin)

Comment: does it work with `child_process.spawn('echo')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working for me...

The script (named flux) I am using for testing is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read x ; do echo $x ; done
```

And the code need linebreaks

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');

program = child_process.execFile('./flux');
fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
program.stdout.pipe(fileStream);
program.stdin.end("hello world!\r\n");
```

Comment: f*** my life.  I'll test it again and update my question if the errors . Thanks : )

Comment: Without `/r/n` the file.txt will be empty. Why?

Comment: I'll put my C code in the question. Note that i read %s in that, so, \n is not needed.

Comment: I noticed you unaccepted my answer. Do you need more help ? Please post the error message if you still have an error.

Comment: Sorry Leszek. I updated my question, "update 2" is still unanswered.